# C# Webrowser SetAttribute with the same ids

Tags: c#, setattribute

I have two html forms on a website, both with the same input name, and the same submit button name.

How do I go about filling in both of the input boxes, and clicking both of the forms?

I would like to have an int variable to keep track of what one was last clicked ( ie. so I can click the first one, go back to the page and then click the second one!

I tried this but had no luck in general with filling in both boxes with my name:

```
foreach (HtmlElement he in webBrowser1.Document.All.GetElementsByName("name"))
        {
            try
            {
                webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("name").SetAttribute("value", "TestUser");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write("\nError: " + ex);
            }
        }
```

Any tips or ideas would help out a lot :$

Comment: Surely `he.SetAttribute("value", ...)` ?

Comment: Is there anyway I could do like he[1] or something just to do the first one?

Comment: Remove the loop and just `webBrowser1.Document.All.GetElementsByName("name")[0].SetAttribute("value", "TestUser")`

Comment: Thanks a ton! I finally got it working, I didn't realize that was the way to do it! :)